# Is there any low-level difference between object with static fields and global object

Tags: c++, static

For example I have a structure with static fields (variant 1):

```
// MyPool.h
struct MyPool {
  static unsigned int capacity;
  static unsigned int numOfAllocatedObjects;
}

// MyPool.cpp
unsigned int MyPool::capacity {1024};
unsigned int MyPool::numOfAllocatedObjects {0};
```

How it differs from (variant 2):

```
// MyPool.h
struct MyPool {
  unsigned int capacity {1024};
  unsigned int numOfAllocatedObjects {0};
}

extern MyPool MyGlobalPool;

// MyPool.cpp
MyPool MyGlobalPool {};
```

I know that I can't create another instance of `MyPool` using variant 1. But I'm interested if there are some low level differences?
In terms of performance maybe? Or it's the same?

Comment: C++ is really, really complicated when it comes to things like this.  optimizers can do all sorts of things depending on the actual code and what it does, making the only way to really know by trying both, measuring, and comparing the results.  First, try to write code that easy to understand and to maintain, then if you find the performance lacking, run a profiler to find the spots in the code that need to be optimized.

Comment: `extern MyPool MyGlobalPool;` -- Maintaining this and making the linker happy is a pain in the neck.  *If* you had to choose, go with the first variant.

Comment: I think there is difference in initialization global are initilized first.

Comment: The order of construction of members of an object (during construction of that object) is specified by the standard, even if that object is a global.   The order of construction of distinct global objects is unspecified in several cases (e.g. if they are in different compilation units).